# zlib build error with GHC

Tags: haskell, zlib, ghc, cabal, archlinux

I'm using a VM with the following configuration:

- Arch Linux (3.0-ARCH kernel)
- GHC 7.0.3
- cabal-install 0.10.2
- Cabal library 1.10.1.0

When I try to build zlib using cabal...

```
$ cabal install zlib
```

I get the following output:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading zlib-0.5.3.2...
Configuring zlib-0.5.3.2...
Preprocessing library zlib-0.5.3.2...
Stream.hsc:86:21: error: missing binary operator before token "("
Stream.hsc: In function ‘main’:
Stream.hsc:86:21: error: missing binary operator before token "("
Stream.hsc:86:21: error: missing binary operator before token "("
compiling dist/build/Codec/Compression/Zlib/Stream_hsc_make.c failed (exit code 1)
command was: /usr/bin/gcc -c dist/build/Codec/Compression/Zlib/Stream_hsc_make.c -o dist/build/Codec/Compression/Zlib/Stream_hsc_make.o -fno-stack-protector -fno-stack-protector -D__GLASGOW_HASKELL__=700 -Dlinux_BUILD_OS -Dlinux_HOST_OS -Dx86_64_BUILD_ARCH -Dx86_64_HOST_ARCH -I/usr/lib/ghc-7.0.3/bytestring-0.9.1.10/include -I/usr/lib/ghc-7.0.3/base-4.3.1.0/include -I/usr/lib/ghc-7.0.3/include -I/usr/lib/ghc-7.0.3/include -I/usr/lib/ghc-7.0.3/include/
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
zlib-0.5.3.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Can anyone shed some light on this build error?

---

**Edit:** Here's a snippet from Stream.hsc with line numbers:

```
 82 import Foreign
 83          ( Word8, Ptr, nullPtr, plusPtr, peekByteOff, pokeByteOff, mallocBy    tes  
 84          , ForeignPtr, FinalizerPtr, newForeignPtr_, addForeignPtrFinalizer
 85          , withForeignPtr, touchForeignPtr )
 86 #if MIN_VERSION_base(4,4,0)
 87 import Foreign.ForeignPtr.Unsafe ( unsafeForeignPtrToPtr )
 88 import System.IO.Unsafe          ( unsafePerformIO )
 89 #else
 90 import Foreign ( unsafeForeignPtrToPtr, unsafePerformIO )
 91 #endif
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For some reason, the `MIN_VERSION_base` macro doesn't get expanded, thus the preprocessor sees the condition `MIN_VERSION_base(4,4,0)` which it of course cannot handle. I've not yet found out why the macro isn't expanded, but workarounds are

1. install zlib-0.5.3.1 instead
2. unpack the tarball and edit `Codec/Compression/Zlib/Stream.hsc` to remove the offending macro (you're using 7.0.3, so your base version is 4.3.1.0, you can replace the macro with 0)

**Edit:** After poking around a bit, I found out that to hide these preprocessor directives, which aren't intended for `hsc2hs` to process, they have to be masked by an extra '#'. Bug report underway.

Comment: Hah, it's funny, I ran into the exact same problem today :)

Comment: @Phyx proper solution found, should not be long until it reaches hackage.

Comment: Note that cabal-install from HEAD (due to be 0.14, although it might be in 0.12 as well, I'm not sure) does pass these macros to hsc2hs. This is probably how the bug got introduced: whoever added the macros, had a development version of cabal-install.

Comment: Yes, sorry folks. I tested with several ghc versions but seems I was using a recent Cabal lib version with every ghc version I used. I've fixed it and uploaded a new version.

Answer (score 12):

On Ubuntu, I fixed (or really, avoided) a similar error with

```sh
sudo apt-get install libghc-zlib-dev  libghc-zlib-bindings-dev
```

(I don't know if both are needed.)

Comment: You are a saviour. This magic incantation worked for me. I am on Zorin 12.1

Answer (score 6):

I'm still encountering this with the haskell package zlib-0.5.4.2 on GHC 7.8.4. I think the issue is a non-standard location of the library. I solved it by hand-installing zlib 1.2.8 and then doing:

```
cabal install zlib --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/local/lib --extra-include-dir=/usr/local/include
```

Comment: That fixed it for me. Thanks! In particular, these can be added in `~/.cabal/config`.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason is that the zlib C library headers are missing on your machine. You might instead try to use the Arch Linux "Haskell Platform" or [haskell-zlib](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/haskell-zlib/) packages, which resolve C dependencies for you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  Unfortunately, both the **extra/haskell-platform** (2011.2.0.0-4) and **extra/haskell-zlib** (0.5.3.1-2.1) packages are already installed.  Really all I've done in the VM is **sudo pacman -S haskell-platform && cabal install virthualenv && mkdir -p src/proj && cd src/proj && virthualenv && source .virthualenv/bin/activate && cabal install yesod**.  The yesod build broke due to zlib error.

Comment: I got the exact same message, and I've got the zlib C library headers present. Adding the missing # made it work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand this error, but it happened to me also earlier today while trying to install Agda 2.3 using GHC 7.4. Saizan from #agda suggested that I try

```sh
cabal unpack zlib
cd zlib-0.5.3.2/
runghc Setup configure --user; runghc Setup build; runghc Setup install
```

This proved effective. But I'm still in the dark about what's actually the problem.

Still, as it worked, I thought I'd share.

Comment: Thank you for sharing.  I ran the suggested commands but got the same error when performing **runghc Setup build**.  I've updated my question to include a snippet from Stream.hsc.

Comment: +1 because this solution works *after* updating Stream.hsc as suggested by Daniel Fischer

Comment: @JonNadal does the answer need to be updated to indicate you should edit it before running?

Comment: @poolie It's up to you.  Daniel's solution is correct; this one just provides some helpful follow-up.  To clarify what needs to be done before performing **runghc**: (1) determine base version: **cabal info base|grep 'Versions installed:'** (2) If version >= 4.4.0, change  **#if MIN_VERSION_base(4,4,0)** to **#if 1**.  Otherwise, change it to **#if 0**.

Comment: @poolie, I should have also mentioned that Stream.hsc is located at Codec/Compression/Zlib/Stream.hsc in the zlib directory.