# Braving cabal hell on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: haskell, ghc, zlib, cabal

Attempting to travel through the entirety of Cabal dependency hell in 12.04 precise build of Ubuntu, and I have been making slow progress.

My first bash command 
`cabal install --allow-newer` yields the following message at the bottom of a long list of new packages:

> ```
> cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken by the
> reinstalls:
>     regex-posix-0.95.1 
>     regex-compat-0.95.1 
> Use `--force-reinstalls` if you want to install anyway.
> ```

(NOTE: A force reinstall was never ran.)

How can I fix these packages and finish the process of installing cabal?
I must stay in 12.04 and cabal has been updated.

`cabal install ad --reorder-goals` ended up getting it to install.

However I am still not out of cabal hell, as I now have to deal with:

> cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing: aeson -any, json-schema -any, monad-logger -any, mtl -any, persistent -any, persistent-postgresql ==2.1.6, persistent-template -any, rest-core -any, rest-snap -any, snap-core -any, snap-server -any, text -any"

when I attempt to execute `cabal build`

UPDATE: The dependencies needed list has shrunk to:
monad-logger, persistent, (Fine name for a cabal installer.)
persistant-postgresql == 2.1.6
'persistent-template
rest-snap
snap-core
snap-server

So aside from persistant-postgresql any version will work.

Update 2 : Good news though, Running `sudo apt-get install libghc-zlib-dev` 
Uncovers an interesting roadblock.

While trying as suggested in one of the answers in this question : [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961413/zlib-build-error-with-ghc/9030944#9030944/%20Question)

to install libghc-zlib-bindings-dev, which installed fine, and libghc-zlib-dev.

The zlib is the dependency that is in the way right now. Once that installs progress will continue.

Current warning on the `libghc-zlib-dev` install attempt :

> warning: Please check that your locale settings:
>   LANGUAGE = (unset),
>   LC_ALL = (unset),
>   LANG = "en_US.UTF-8
>   are supported and installed on your system.

also

> perl: warning : Falling back to the standard locale ("C").

displayed.

Perhaps this can help us dig deeper into the investigation.

Trudge out of cabal hell we must.

Pretty sure this is the place to plant the red flag :

> #include "zlib.h"
>
> ^
>
> compilation terminated.
>   setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.2.0-x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.1: Missing dependency on > a
>   foreign library:
>   * Missing (or bad) header file: zlib.h
>   * Missing C library: z

Man I wish this site would have auto Ctrl - C Ctrl -V formating, how awesome would that be?

Comment: Remove all your packages with `rm -rf ~/.ghc ~/.cabal`. Don't globally install packages that have no reason to be installed globally. Use [sandboxes](http://coldwa.st/e/blog/2013-08-20-Cabal-sandbox.html). Use [`cabal exec` or `cabal repl`](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2ywbwy/how_do_i_tell_ghc_that_i_have_a_cabal_sandbox/) to run your programs more interactively inside the sandboxed environment. And, last but not least, use [Stackage](http://www.stackage.org/).

Comment: Or just unregister `regex-posix-0.95.1` and `regex-compat-0.95.1` and anything that depends on them and if you want to keep them, try reinstalling them at the same time as whatever other package you are trying to install.

Comment: I would recommend using a cabal sandbox, one per project, if you happen to have a recent cabal.

Comment: @9000 I have a sandbox in the project. Anything special that needs to be done to utilize it? I thought `cabal build` would be enough.

Comment: @MarcusViníciusMonteiro the `rm -rf ~/.ghc ~/.cabal` was ran and I tried to use Stackage, I came across the same errors with a Stackage install. 

Not at the point where I can run anything yet, as I am still trying to build here.

Comment: The same errors? Why don't you put all the packages you want to install in your question, so we can replicate it?

Comment: @hellyale: Good to know. I just thought that interference between different projects might be the culprit.

Comment: @MarcusViníciusMonteiro The packages that are left are in the question. The current roadblock is adding the libghc-zlib-dev. I am not sure, but that likely might be the final roadblock.

Comment: Not only the packages left, but the entire process that lead to it. All the cabal installs since the beginning. I want to see if this error repeats itself if I try to install all the packages you want to install using Stackage inside a sandbox.

Comment: @MarcusViníciusMonteiro I wasn't keeping track of the process until I encountered the issue.

Comment: Then I think that the best thing you can do is follow my first comment. It's good to not clutter your global environment, not only with cabal packages but with any programs. [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) and [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) are some good tools for that.

Comment: for the `zlib.h` headers: those should be in `zlib1g-dev` - you should usually be able to install those with `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev` - I have no ubuntu 12.04 at hand but you should be able to find the right one (if this isn't) - start `synaptic` and search for packages with the name `zlib` (`sudo aptitude zlib` from the bash/terminal should also do) - then look for one with `-dev` that's usually where the headers are ;) - after this you can continue your `cabal` adventures ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to build just a single package, and the issue is that it has many dependencies.

The best way to install all the dependencies (since a "build" unlike an "install" won't find a solution to installing them all for you) is just to (preferably in a sandbox) run `cabal install --dependencies-only`. This will also solve them all simultaneously, rather than one-by-one where incompatible local choices may be made...

Comment: Luckily the machine now has 14.04